# How to solve error "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1"

Tags: java, android

**I have the problem like this :**
[image: Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1]

**This is my source code :**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    JualBarangDBHelper dbcenter;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    String[] daftar;
    ListView list;
    public static Home hom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        dbcenter = new JualBarangDBHelper(this);
        hom = this;
        RefreshList();
    }


    public void RefreshList() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jualbarang", null);
        daftar = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int cc = 0; cc < cursor.getCount(); cc++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(cc);
            daftar[cc] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
        }
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, daftar));
        list.setSelected(true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                final String selection = daftar[arg2]; //.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail.class);
                i.putExtra("no", selection);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        ((ArrayAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: which line in your code is line 40?

Comment: line 40 is daftar[cc] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
any error or wrong code from that?

Comment: Perhaps your cursor is empty.

Comment: You should wrap all the logic below "cursor.movetofirst();" in an IF statement, and make it "if(cursor.moveToFirst())"

Comment: since moveToFirst returns a boolean to indicate whether it succeeded or not.

Comment: You might want to look into using a CursorAdapter instead of an ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check the cursor.getCount() if  it is greater than zero then do

```
while(cursor.movetoFirst())
{
 //Your code

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean like this brother?

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
        for (int cc = 0; cc < cursor.getCount(); cc++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(cc);
            daftar[cc] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
        }
    }
```